# Polymorphic Association and extra id field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphic-associations

I need some help with polymorphic associations. Below is my structure:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_ancestry
  has_many :categorisations
end

class Categorisation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :categorisable, polymorphic: true
end

class classifiedAd < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :categorisation, as: :categorisable
end
```

And here is my schema.rb

```
create_table "classifiedads", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.text     "body"
  t.decimal  "price"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
add_index "classifiedads", ["user_id"], name: "index_classifiedads_on_user_id", using: :btree

create_table "categories", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "ancestry"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
add_index "categories", ["ancestry"], name: "index_categories_on_ancestry", using: :btree

create_table "categorisations", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "category_id"
  t.integer  "categorisable_id"
  t.string   "categorisable_type"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

It seems like the associations is correct as when I'm in the console I can do the appropriate commands and all seems to return the right results, for example: `Category.first.categorisations` or `ClassifedAd.first.categorisation`. But what I don't understand is saving the association from the `Create` and editing the record via the `Update` actions. I'm using simple_form to create my forms and when looking at the params I get the below:

```
{"title"=>"Tiger",
 "body"=>"Huge Helicopter",
 "price"=>"550.0",
 "categorisation"=>"5"}
```

and this fails to update or even create as I get this error : `Categorisation(#70249667986640) expected, got String(#70249634794540)` My controller actions code are below:

```
def create
  @classified = Classifiedad.new(classifiedad_params)
  @classified.user = current_user
  @classified.save
end

def update
  @classified.update(classifiedad_params)
end

def classifiedad_params
  params.require(:classifiedad).permit(:title, :body, :price)
end
```

I think it has something to do with the params as categorisation should be within a sub hash of results, is this right? Also, I need to do something extra within the actions, but what? What the `params[:categorisation]` value needs to do is save the number into the `Categorisations.category_id` table column and also save the polymorphic association. This table will be used across other models, which will also be a `has_one` association, as the user will only be able to select one category for each record. I really hope someone can help me here as the more I look into it the more I get confused :S Please let me know if you ned anymore info from me.

I'm using Rails 4 and Ruby 2

**EDIT 2**

I managed to get something working but I'm still not sure if its right. Below is the update code for the `Create` and `Update` actions. Would be good to know if there is a better way of doing this?

```
def create
  @classified = Classifiedad.new(classifiedad_params)
  @classified.user = current_user

  **** NEW 
  cat = Categorisation.new(category_id: params[:classified][:categorisation])
  @classified.categorisation = cat 
  **** END NEW

  @classified.save
end

def update
  **** NEW
  @classified.categorisation.update_attribute(:category_id, params[:classified][:categorisation])
  **** END NEW

  @classified.update(classifiedad_params)
end
```